# Putting more info in a grails wars

Tags: grails

Grails allows us to package up a war very easily with

```
grails war
```

I would likemore meta - info somewhere in the war. What time it was built at etc.   Is there a switch that will create such a file and fill it with meta info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no switch to add metadata about the war creation but you can add/delete contents to war during war generation by using this entry in BuildConfig.

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    copy(todir: "${stagingDir}") {
        fileset(dir:"${basedir}/path/to/your/meta-info/files") {
            //Exclude unwanted files
            exclude(name:"**/excluded-file")
        }
    }

    //In case you want to remove something from the staging dir
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/<deleteSome.jar>")
}
```