# Exclude a transitive dependency

Tags: grails, dependency-management

In a Grails 2.5 project when I run `grails war` a transitive dependency `log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar` is included in the `WEB-INF/lib` dir of the .war file.

This .jar is causing problems at runtime, so I tried excluding it by adding the following to `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        excludes 'log4j-over-slf4j'
    }
}
```

but it didn’t work - any suggestions for how I can prevent this dependency from being included in the .war file?

Comment: The problem here is you are trying to use dependency management to mange something that is outside the scope of that. When you put something in the `lib` directory that's not a managed dependency that's a manual dependency. Either manage it using dependency resolution and remove it from the lib directory or manually (script) the removal of the jar when building the war. Those are your choices.

Comment: War creation hooks (`grails.war.resources`) can be used to remove that jar. See here for details http://stackoverflow.com/a/18316364/2051952.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I don't have any dependencies in the `/lib` dir of this project